# trying to display data from my table into listview in android whats wrong?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, listview

as I mentioned in the title

I am trying to display data from my table into listview but when I open the emulator it stops immediately and I think i have an error nullpointer or something like that .. or I do not really now ..

here is my code:

### JAVA

MainActivity.java :

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ListView PersonsList;
DataBaseAdapter  helper;
private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    helper = new DataBaseAdapter(this);

    displayListView();

}


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)


private void displayListView() {


    Cursor cursor = helper.fetchAllPersons();

    // The desired columns to be bound
    String[] columns = new String[]{

            DataBaseAdapter.Helper.PERSON_NAME,
            DataBaseAdapter.Helper.GENDER,
    };

    // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
    int[] to = new int[]{
            R.id.personName,
            R.id.personGender,

    };

    // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
    //as well as the layout information
    dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
            this, R.layout.single_person_item,
            cursor,
            columns,
            to,
            0);

    PersonsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.personsListView);
    PersonsList.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
 }
 }
```

fetcAllPpersons() in DataBaseAdapter.java ::

```
   public Cursor fetchAllPersons() {

    SQLiteDatabase db = helper.getWritableDatabase();

    Cursor mCursor = db.query(Helper.PERSONS_TABLE, new String[]     {Helper.PERSON_ID,Helper.PERSON_NAME,Helper.DATE_OF_BIRTH,Helper.GENDER,Helper.ADDRESS},
            null, null, null, null, null);

    if (mCursor != null) {
        mCursor.moveToFirst();
    }
    return mCursor;
}
```

---

xml:

activity_main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"      android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity"
>


<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addnewperson"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addnewperson"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/addnewperson">

  <ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/personsListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />
</ScrollView>
```

single_person_item.xml :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="6dip" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/personName" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:text="Medium Text"
    android:id="@+id/personGender" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

where PERSONS_TABLE is the table i want to show some infromation from

where is the problem ??

( the problem is most likely here :

```
   dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this, R.layout.single_person_item,
        cursor,
        columns,
        to,
        0);
```

)

but i can not detect it
thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

One problem I am seeing in the code (there can be others as well) in your layout file the ListView should be inside scrollview. Also it would be helpful if you can attach the error logs

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addnewperson"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/addnewperson"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/addnewperson">




<ListView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/personsListView"
    android:layout_below="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: yes i have edited it now

but the same problem 

the program stop unexpectedly